# RadDropDownList OnSelectedIndexChanged event not firing in server

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, telerik, cascadingdropdown

I have a web application that uses a few dropdown lists that are nested. (Selection of DDL1 will be a parameter for DDL2 etc).

My problem is when I run my application with Visual Studio this DDL1 works as expected firing the SelectedIndexChanged event populating DDL2.

When I publish the same code to the server and access the web application DDL1's SelectedIndexChanged event doesn't fire.

What could be the problem to this?

Here is my Code,

```html
<telerik:RadDropDownList ID="RadDropDownList_Warehouse" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_Warehouse" CausesValidation="false" DataTextField="WarehouseName" DataValueField="WarehouseId" DefaultMessage="Select..." Font-Size="12px" Skin="Metro"
Width="260px" ValidationGroup="save" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadDropDownList_Warehouse_SelectedIndexChanged" ViewStateMode="Enabled" EnableViewState="true">
</telerik:RadDropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource_Warehouse" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:STNRequisitionConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT wd.WarehouseId, wd.WarehouseName, vrmpm.IsDeleted FROM WarehouseDetails AS wd INNER JOIN V_RequestMakerPermissionMatrix AS vrmpm ON wd.WarehouseId = vrmpm.WarehouseId WHERE (vrmpm.UserName = @username) AND (vrmpm.IsDeleted = 0)">
  <SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="HiddenField1" Name="username" PropertyName="Value" />
  </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator_Warehouse" runat="server" ControlToValidate="RadDropDownList_Warehouse" ErrorMessage="Can not be empty!" Font-Bold="False" Font-Size="12px" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="save"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

```
protected void RadDropDownList_Warehouse_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, DropDownListEventArgs e)
{
    string message = STNLogger.CreateMessage("Warehouse Selected Index Changed Method Fired");
    STNLogger.LogFileWrite(message);
    string factory = RadDropDownList_Warehouse.SelectedText.Trim();
    List<string> buList = new List<string>();
    buList = mr.GetBUsForPlants(factory);
    RadDropDownList_BusinessUnit.DataSource = buList;
    RadDropDownList_BusinessUnit.DataBind();
}
```

I used this LogFileWrite() to see if this method was executed at all in the server but no. This event is not fired in the server, whereas in Visual Studio it is. Please help!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to test it on your VS using the database you have on the server.

Comment: @FeliceM I am using the same database in both scenarios (in my visual studio and in the server). So the data couldn't be affecting this :(

Comment: From my previous experiences this could be a connection problem with the DB once you are on the server. I would check if you can read something from your DB once the app is deployed on the server.